# core-tooltip is open when menu is open when used with a paper-menu-button

Tags: polymer

I started with

```
      <core-tooltip label="{{editor.userEditor.username}}"
          position="left">
        <paper-icon-button id="accountbutton" icon="account-circle"
            halign="right">
        </paper-icon-button>
      </core-tooltip>
```

which is pretty textbook and works fine.

Now I want the icon button to be a menu instead so I changed it to

```
      <core-tooltip label="{{editor.userEditor.username}}"
          position="left">
        <paper-menu-button id="accountbutton" icon="account-circle"
            halign="right">
          <paper-item label="Logout {{editor.userEditor.username}}">
            <a href="{{editor.userEditor.logoutUrl}}"></a>
          </paper-item>
        </paper-menu-button>
      </core-tooltip>
```

Problem is (somewhat unsurprisingly maybe in hindsight) the tooltip is open when the menu is open to. Obviously that is undesirable.

How do I avoid that?

See jsbin.com/saziziwixu

Comment: This probably has to do with the focus state of the menu. Can you post a live jsbin?

Comment: sure. See http://jsbin.com/saziziwixu

Comment: Workaround: https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/issues/17